# flutter upgrade - fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/switch_adaptive 2

Tags: flutter, git

I am trying to upgrade flutter but now the below.  I have seen this before.  How do I resolve this?

```
flutter upgrade
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/switch_adaptive 2
error: https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git did not send all necessary objects
  Command: git fetch --tags
```